# Python script that runs in all excel rows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a script that will take the values of each parameters in excel file (Data, Time, Name) and put the value in a variable.

For example: (I can't upload an image so I will try to write it here like a file)

```
         Date   Time  Name
row 1    04-Apr 12:00 Johny

row 2    04-Apr 18:00 Paul

row 3    05-Apr 10:00 Mark
```

I want the script to take the values of "Date:04-Apr" , "Time:12:00" , "Name:Johny" and will put the value in variables.

I tried the following:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

class Alns(object):
    def __init__(self, Date, Time, Who):
      self.Date = Date
      self.Time = Time
      self.Who = Who
    def lstfunc(self):
      return[self.Date, self.Time, self.Who]

wb = open_workbook('bonvos.xlsx')
for sheet in wb.sheets():
number_of_rows = sheet.nrows
number_of_columns = sheet.ncols

items = []

rows = []
for row in range(1, number_of_rows):
    values = []
    for col in range(number_of_columns):
        value  = (sheet.cell(row,col).value)
        values.append(value)
    item = Alns(*values)
    items.append(item)

for item in items:
    print(item)
```

I tried to return a list for each row, but I received memory address output rather than values.

The script needs to run row by row and after each row will print "Date is: Time is: Name is:"

for example:

for row 1:
"Date is:04-Apr Time is:12:00 Name is:Johny"

for row 2, for row 3 , etc.

Comment: I don't think your question complies to the standards for a StackOverflow question. You can check there (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find how to ask a good question. Please show you tried to solve the issue and give us what you tried.

Comment: You can open your excel as dataframe and iterate over rows with iterrows fonction.

Comment: As @Jao said, what have you tried?

Comment: Hi, sorry for this, I have updated the question, hope that you can help me guys

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to print the object itself, so you have used the default `object.__repr__(obj)`.

You must change the last part of your code to:

```
for item in items:
    print('Date is:%s Time is:%s Who is:%s'%tuple(item.lstfunc()))
```

or you can override the `__repr__` method:

```
    def __repr__(self):
      return 'Date is:%s Time is:%s Who is:%s'%(self.Date, self.Time, self.Who)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to put each parameter to a variable and to use it not just for print.

Comment: You can simply do that. E.g.  item.Date refers to the Date field of the item.

Comment: Were you successful to use it? You can also use e.g. `date, time, who = item.lstfunc()` in your loop, so date, time, and who will be local variables.